# How to scroll page by page (div by div)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have working on a one page (potentially) viral website and the backend being done, I am perfecting the front.

Each div (page) is 100% widht and 100% height so full page. I want to create a jQuery function to trigger when the user scrolls (using trackpad, mouse or keyboard.) and whether the users goes up or down, scroll to the previous or next div/page (while preventing the default scrolling motion.)

Any idea how could that be done? This is my HTML.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <article class="card">page 1</article>
    <article class="card">page 2</article>
    <article class="card">page 3</article>
    <article class="card">page 4</article>
    <article class="card">page 5</article>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.card').height($(window).height());
    });
    $(window).resize(function() { $('.card').height($(window).height()); });
    $(window).trigger('resize');
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

this jquery method should get you started:

```
<!-- Scroller -->
        <script>
        var curPage = 0;

        var pages = [
            "#page1" => 0,
            "#page2" => 1,
            "#page3" => 2,
            "#page4" => 3,
            "#page5" => 4,
            "#page6" => 5,
            "#page7" => 6
        ];

        var name = ".module_row_";

        var scrollable = true;

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
                    if (curPage > 0 && scrollable) {
                        --curPage;
                        scrollable = false;
                        jQuery('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: jQuery(name + curPage).offset().top
                        }, 500, function() {
                            scrollable = true;
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (curPage < pages.length && scrollable) {
                        ++curPage;
                        scrollable = false;
                        jQuery('body, html').animate({
                            scrollTop: jQuery(name + curPage).offset().top
                        }, 500, function() {
                            scrollable = true;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            jQuery(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
                    if (curPage < pages && scrollable) {
                        ++curPage;
                        scrollable = false;
                        jQuery('body, html').animate({
                            scrollTop: jQuery(name + curPage).offset().top
                        }, 500, function() {
                            scrollable = true;
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    if (curPage > 0 && scrollable) {
                        --curPage;
                        scrollable = false;
                        jQuery('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: jQuery(name + curPage).offset().top
                        }, 500, function() {
                            scrollable = true;
                        });
                    }
                }

             });
        });
        </script>
```